# If HTML text equals value, onclick change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, I have tried a few ways of doing this but nothing has worked. I am hoping someone here can tell me what I am doing wrong. Below is a step-by-step of what I am trying to achieve.

`#info-NUMBER-btn` displays `Click to display more information`.
`#info-NUMBER` CSS is set to `display: none`.

When `#info-NUMBER-btn` is clicked:
- Corresponding `#info-NUMBER-btn` displays `Click to display less information`.
- Corresponding `#info-NUMBER` CSS is set to `display: inline-block`.

```js
/* Jquery */

$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#info-1-btn").text("Click to display more information");
     $("#info-2-btn").text("Click to display more information");
     $("#info-3-btn").text("Click to display more information");
     $("#info-4-btn").text("Click to display more information");
     $("#info-5-btn").text("Click to display more information");
     
     if($("#info-1-btn").text("Click to display more information")) {
      $("#info-1-btn").click(function () {
       $(this).text("Click to display less information");
       $("#info-1").css("display", "inline-block");
      });
     } else if($("#info-1").text("Click to display less information")) {
      $("#info-1-btn").click(function() {
       $(this).text("Click to display more information");
       $("#info-1").css("display", "none");
      });
     }
     
     
     if($("#info-2-btn").text("Click to display more information")) {
      $("#info-2-btn").click(function () {
       $(this).text("Click to display less information");
       $("#info-2").css("display", "inline-block");
      });
     } else {
      $("#info-2-btn").click(function() {
       $(this).text("Click to display more information");
       $("#info-2").css("display", "none");
      });
     }
     
     
     if($("#info-5-btn").text("Click to display more information")) {
      $("#info-5-btn").click(function () {
       $(this).text("Click to display less information");
       $("#info-5").css("display", "inline-block");
      });
     } else {
      $("#info-5-btn").click(function() {
       $(this).text("Click to display more information");
       $("#info-5").css("display", "none");
      });
     }
    });
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="info-5" class="hire-equipment-more-information">
  <table class="hire-equipment-more-information-table" cellpadding="15px">
    <tr>
      <th>Length:</th>
      <th>Material:</th>
      <th>HP:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7.5m</td>
      <td>Aluminium</td>
      <td>225</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br />
<a id="info-5-btn" class="hire-equipment-item-link"></a>
```

Comment: You should do the if statements in your click eventhandler, and not the way you are doing it now. Also by doing `$('#id').text('text')`  you are setting the text of the element. I suggest you go back to the basics...

Comment: You shouldn't be binding click events based on the textual content of an element. Instead, listen to click events and THEN determine what action to perform. The action can be determined using a hidden variable or data attribute that stores the toggle state of the content.

Comment: @Terry This may be a dumb question, but I am still quite new to this. How would I go about adding a data attribute storing the toggle state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets examine this line of code

```
if($("#info-1-btn").text("Click to display more information")) {
```

This should be:

```
if($("#info-1-btn").text() === "Click to display more information")) {
```

The `text` function is an overloaded function. If you pass in no value, it will return you the text inside the element.

If you pass in a value, it will modify the text, and return the jQuery object again (which will be a truthy value).

Now lets look at your overall logic.

Your code is testing the state of the buttons once, when the document loads. It should be testing the state of the button as part of the click handler.

See this complete code example: http://plnkr.co/edit/HLsLcKrRY3OqK6w44bXp?p=preview

It might not match your requirements exactly, but it demonstrates how you test the state of the button inside a click handler.

It also demonstrates how you can use a custom attribute (in this case, `data-target`) to link a button to a div block.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="toggleButton" data-target="buttonOneInfo"></button>
  <br />
  <div class="toggleTarget" id="buttonOneInfo">
    Here's some information about the first item
  </div>
  <button class="toggleButton" data-target="buttonTwoInfo"></button>
  <br />
  <div class="toggleTarget" id="buttonTwoInfo">
    Here's some information about the second item
  </div>
  <button class="toggleButton" data-target="buttonThreeInfo"></button>
  <br />
  <div class="toggleTarget" id="buttonThreeInfo">
    Here's some information about the third item
  </div>


</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.toggleTarget').hide();
    $(".toggleButton")
      .text("Click to display more information")
      .click(function() {
        var toggleTargetId = $(this).attr('data-target');
        var toggleTarget = $(document.getElementById(toggleTargetId));

        if ($(this).text() === 'Click to display more information') {
          $(this).text('Click to display less information');
          toggleTarget.show();
        } else {
          $(this).text('Click to display more information');
          toggleTarget.hide();
        }
      });
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: There is so much more that can be changed... Like attaching the click handler inside an if statement?

Comment: It seems to display properly when clicked, but when clicked again, it does not change display CSS

Comment: @Jesse: This is due to how you have wired code up to your click handler. I've added some more to my answer for this.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I like your easy and simple method, however how would I go about finding the `.hire-equipment-more-information` and changing its `display` to `inline-block` and back again with their corresponding buttons?

Comment: @Jesse - You can do this by linking each button to a div via a custom attribute. I've modified my example.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd You sir are a legend. That worked a charm, and now reading over it, it makes perfect sense and is very easy to understand!

One last question, but how would I animate the change? I am messing around with it now to try and see if I can pull it off :)

Comment: Nevermind! I realised that you can just do it by expanding the `.show` to `.show(2000, "swing");`

Answer (score 3):

You could make it a lot more easy for yourself, by binding not to the element id's, but to use your class `hire-equipment`.

This way you don't have to bind to 5 different buttons that in essence do the same thing.

Once you hit the eventHandler, you can use the first argument of the function, to check from which button you are coming and take the appropriate action.

As an example, I just created the 5 elements, and 1 event handler.

The `$(selector).click()` will bind to all elements sharing the selector ( in my case `hire-equipment`), and then, it will check from which button it's coming, select the parent node (the div surrounding the button, title and description), search the description element, and toggle it's hidden class. The buttons text will then change depending on it's text.

It's not fully how your example is built, but it's an example of making your event handlers a bit more generic.

```js
$('.hire-equipment').click(function(event) {
  var sourceElement = $(event.target);
  $(sourceElement).parent().find('.description').toggleClass('hidden');
  if ($(sourceElement).text() === 'Show more information') {
    $(sourceElement).text('Show less information');
  } else {
    $(sourceElement).text('Show more information');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="title">Title of item</p>
  <div class="description hidden">This is a description</div>
  <button type="button" class="hire-equipment">Show more information</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="title">Title of item</p>
  <div class="description hidden">This is a description</div>
  <button type="button" class="hire-equipment">Show more information</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="title">Title of item</p>
  <div class="description hidden">This is a description</div>
  <button type="button" class="hire-equipment">Show more information</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="title">Title of item</p>
  <div class="description hidden">This is a description</div>
  <button type="button" class="hire-equipment">Show more information</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trimmed the fat off of OP's jQuery. The following procedure is roughly outlined here:

- Primary method used is `toggleClass()`
- At least 2 classes are required to indicate a state of `.info-btn`
- The big advantage of using classes is that you can add more styles to each class that would enhance `.info-btn`'s state. ex. `color`, `background-color`

Further details are commented in the source of the Snippet below:

#### SNIPPET

```js
/* jQuery */

// Alternate styntax for $(document).ready(
$(function() {

  // Click on ANYTHING with the class .info-btn
  $(".info-btn").on("click", function(e) {

    // Prevent .info-btn from jumping when clicked
    e.preventDefault();

    /* `this` or .info-btn will toggle between the 
    | classes of .more and .less
    | See CSS for details of expected behavior of
    | .info-btn in both states
    */
    $(this).toggleClass('more less');
  });
});
```

```css
.info-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Both classes use the :after pseudo-selector
| The value of content will complete the 
| string: "Click to display"...
*/

a.more:after {
  content: ' more information';
}
a.less:after {
  content: ' less information';
}
button.less:before {
  content: 'less ';
}
button.less:after {
  content: ' more';
}
button.more:before {
  content: 'more ';
}
button.more:after {
  content: ' less';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="info-5" class="rental-info">
  <table class="rental-info-table" cellpadding="15px">
    <tr>
      <th>Length:</th>
      <th>Material:</th>
      <th>HP:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7.5m</td>
      <td>Aluminium</td>
      <td>225</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br />
<a class="info-btn rental-link more">Click to display</a>
<br/>
<button class='info-btn less'>is</button>
<br/>
```